# In an array, find an optimized algorithm for finding sum of lengths of longest subarray with current element being the highest in the subarray

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I have an array something like this [1,3,5]. For each of these elements I need to find the longest subarray in which the current element is the highest. The answer will be sum of lengths of all the subarrays.

Explanation.

index - 0 : Element 1 -> Longest subarray with elements less than current element = [1]

index - 1 : Element 3 -> Longest subarray with elements less than current element = [1,3]

index - 2 : Element 5 -> Longest subarray with elements less than current element = [1,3,5]

Final answer = 1 + 2 + 3 = 6 [length of individual subarrays]

I am able to come up with a brute force O(N ^ 2) for this problem. Is there a better way to solve this problem?

Comment: You need a better example. If the array is sorted, as in your current example, the answer is just `1+2+...+N = N(N+1)/2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll give you 2 hints.

**Hint 1:** A solution with Time complexity and Space complexity `O(n)` is possible.`n` is the number of elements in the given array `Arr`. `dynamic-programming` tag causes the mind to stick to it instead of exploring other possible solutions.

Stop here now and try it yourself before reading further.

.

.

.

.

Intentional gap to avoid making you read 2nd hint unintentionally

.

.

.

.

**Hint 2:** Use Monotonic Stack.

Stop here now and try it yourself before reading further.

I loved solving this problem, Thanks! **The solution below is straight one pass and uses space only for stack.**

Instead of giving a regular style line-by-line algorithm, I'll show you a simulation.

```
Index:  0   1   2   3   4   5   
Arr:    44  91  58  54  7   38
```

[image]

**Is the above given solution correct?**

[image]

Sum of lengths = 17. So, we have a right solution.

**Follow-up question:**
Will the above solution work if duplicates exist in `Arr`? If no, what changes will you make to the above algorithm to make it work? Hint: Would playing around with `>`, `<`, `=` help?

Answer (score 0):

Just record the indexes of the [next greater element](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/next-greater-element) in both directions and look them up for each element. O(n) space and time.